# Сделать невидимой кнопку через 3 секунды

Tags: java, android

Как сделать кнопку невидимой через 3 секунды?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `View.postDelayed(...)`:

```
mButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
   }, 3000);
```

Первый параметр – класс, реализующий интерфейс `Runnable`, второй – задержка в миллисекундах.

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо.